# Running a cron job every 5 minute on arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, cron

I've searched through some answers but nothing seems to clarify my confusion.

I have a cron job I want to run every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /mnt/internal-storage/coindata && shell/command coins update
```

Do I place this in the **/etc/cron.daily** folder or create a **/etc/cron.minutely**?

Also what kind of file I create inside this folder?

Comment: Run `crontab -e` and put it there?

Comment: Whenever I run that I get a terminal with a bunch of tildes on separate lines  and a  "/tmp/crontab.6SjpJh" 0 lines, 0 characters at the bottom of terminal.  All the tutorials I've read state that it's supposed to open an editor but it doesn't.

Comment: That sounds like an editor to me. Probably vi.

Comment: Put the file in `/etc/cron.d` directory. See man page crontab(5). Line format is: `minute hour dom month user command...`. You might have an example in the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution for this is likely to add a line to your crontab. Accessing the crontab file may differ between implementations of cron, so I've provided commands for the two cron implementations in the official Arch repos. If you want a solution that does not require a specific cron implementation, I've written [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397622/running-a-cron-job-every-5-minute-on-arch/397651#397651) that uses systemd/Timers instead.

`crontab -e` or variants of it use the EDITOR environment variable (defaults to vi). If you wish to use a different editor, export it to the EDITOR variable like so:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

where vim is replaced with the editor of your choice.

---

Editing crontab with cronie:

```
crontab -e
```

Editing crontab with fcron:

```
fcrontab -e
```

Add your cron command to the file and save it:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /mnt/internal-storage/coindata && shell/command coins update
```

The format for lines in this file is

```
minute hour day_of_month month day_of_week command
```

If cron is not running, start its daemon.

For cronie: `systemctl start cronie.service`

For fcron: `systemctl start fcron.service`

If you want the commands in the crontab to continue to run after rebooting, make sure that the cron daemon is enabled:

`systemctl enable cronie.service` or `systemctl enable fcron.service`

Answer (score 3):

Arch Linux's built-in timing system is [systemd/Timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers). The Arch Wiki lists several [pros and cons for using it as a cron replacement](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#As_a_cron_replacement). I would add another pro: no cron implementation needs to be installed.

Overall, I'd recommend using a cronjob for simplicity's sake, but this is a solution that should (in theory) work on any Arch installs; the cron implementation irrelevant.

An implementation in Timers (replace TIMERNAME with a name for your timer):

Timer file location: `/etc/systemd/system/TIMERNAME.timer`

---

```
[Unit]
Description=Run TIMERNAME every five minutes

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/15
Persistent=true     

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

---

Timer service file location: `/etc/systemd/system/TIMERNAME.service`

---

```
[Unit]
Description=Run some commands - for use with TIMERNAME.service

[Service]
ExecStart=cd /mnt/internal-storage/coindata && shell/command coins update
# Alternatively could be used to run a script with the above commands in it.
# If your script is located at /usr/local/bin, change the above command to:
#    ExecStart:/usr/local/bin/SCRIPTNAME

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

To start, run:

```
systemctl start TIMERNAME.timer
```

To enable (so that it will continue working after future reboots):

```
systemctl enable TIMERNAME.timer
```

Stopping and disabling follow the same format.